# TabsPagerAdapter class error "Type mismatch"

Tags: android, layout, android-fragments

i am facing a problem in TabsPagerAdapter class the error is showing...`Type mismatch: cannot convert from MapActivity to Fragment`  help me out of this issue.

note

```
class MapActivity extends FragmentActivity

class Directions extends Fragment

class places extends Fragment
```

the `TabsPagerAdapter` class is

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;




public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int index) {

    switch (index) {
    case 0:
        // Map fragment activity
        return new MapActivity();
    case 1:
        // Directions fragment activity
        return new Directions();
    case 2:
        // Places fragment activity
        return new Places();
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // get item count - equal to number of tabs
    return 3;
}

}
```

Comment: You must only return instance of `Fragment`. but here your `MapActivity` is a `FragmentActivity` not a `Fragment`...

Comment: ok , i want to return any type from activity if it is fragment or fragmentActivity and so also

Comment: what changes in code?